# How do I highlight the cell based on it colum name?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table with 4 columns as option 1 to 4 and in the 5th one I have the correct answers. Now I want to highlight only that correct answer using conditional formating

[image: Table]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use conditional formatting with the following formula: `=B$1=$F2`

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment given by cybernetic.nomad we can use
=B$1=$F1 as the formula for conditional formatting